# How do i resolve the file mismatch in this vba script

Tags: vba, csv, excel

I would like to copy data from a csv file into an excel worksheet. There are 11 csv files. 
So far I have this (it is a modified version from a previous post):

```
Sub importData()   
  Dim filenum(0 To 50) As Long
  filenum(0) = 052
  filenum(1) = 060
  filenum(2) = 064
  filenum(3) = 068
  filenum(4) = 070
  filenum(5) = 072
  filenum(6) = 074
  filenum(7) = 076
  filenum(8) = 178
  filenum(9) = 180
  filenum(10) = 182

  Dim sh1 As Worksheet
  On Error GoTo my_handler

  For lngPosition = LBound(filenum) To UBound(filenum)
    Windows(filenum & ".csv").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("30_graphs_w_Macro.xlsm").Activate
    sh1 = Worksheets(filenum)
    sh1.Activate
    Range("A69").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A69").Select

  Next lngPositionlngPositionlngPosition

my_handler:
  MsgBox "All done."
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

However, I am getting a type mismatch over here:

```
Windows(filenum & ".csv").Activate
```

I am not too sure how to fix it. 
Other than this, does the rest of the code look ok? This is my first VBA script...

Answer (score 1):

Filenum is an array, so you need to refer to it using an index

`Windows(filenum & ".csv").Activate` is wrong

Change to:

```
filenum(lngPosition)
```

or

```
filenum(1)
```

Also your `Next` is wrong..

```
Next lngPositionlngPositionlngPosition
```

You must have hit paste too many times

Comment: that part works now, however it still does not get the data and paste it.. any idea why?

Comment: You should avoid the use of `Select` and `Copy` and `Activate` that will be causing you issues I think. Lots of info on Stackoverflow and google about it.