# Updated the vba code and still it gives me a subscript out of range error

Tags: vba, csv, excel, range

This code still gives me an out of subscript error

```
Sub importData2()

  ChDir "C:\Users\Desktop\Java"
  Dim filenum(0 To 10) As Long
  filenum(0) = 052
  filenum(1) = 060
  filenum(2) = 064
  filenum(3) = 068
  filenum(4) = 070
  filenum(5) = 072
  filenum(6) = 074
  filenum(7) = 076
  filenum(8) = 178
  filenum(9) = 180
  filenum(10) = 182

  Dim sh1 As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = Application.Workbooks("30_graphs_w_Macro.xlsm")

  Dim sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim rng2 As Range
  Set rng2 = Range("A69")
  Dim wb2 As Workbook

  For lngposition = LBound(filenum) To UBound(filenum)
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(filenum(lngposition) & ".csv")
    wb2.Worksheets(filenum(lngposition)).rng.Copy wb.Worksheets(filenum(lngposition)).rng2.Paste
  Next lngposition

my_handler:
  MsgBox "All done."
End Sub
```

This still gives me an out of subscript error on the line:

```
Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks(filenum(lngposition) & ".csv")
```

I avoided using .active and .select. .select.

Comment: One tip is to remove the On Error GoTo statement; this will show which line is causing the error and better direct what isn't working.

Comment: Agree with Richard.... that's not an error handler but a false completion message. Also I would remove all of your .Select and Selection. and .Activate references. When you create a macro in Excel it defaults to this language but that's really bad coding. For instance your sh1.Activate, Range("A69").Select and ActiveSheet.Paste lines can be replaced to sh1.Range("A69").Paste. Once you have it cleaned up and remove your On err line you'll be able to properly debug.

Comment: Ok yeah.. that did help, and thanks for the tips. I made the changes in the code. So now I get the message the file 052.csv could not be found. This excel file (with the script) is in the same location as the file 052.csv itself.

Comment: It gives me a runtime error 1004 on this line:
 Workbooks.Add(filenum(lngPosition) & ".csv").Activate
saying it can find the file

Comment: This is not necessarily your current directory. Use `CurDir` function to find where you are and `ChDir` to change it.

Comment: Yes, that took it a litle bit further.. now i get a subscript out of range on this line
Set sh1 = Worksheets(filenum(lngPosition))

Comment: You don't need to ask a new question. Simply edit the old question as they both are the same literally. What is the value of `lngposition` when you get the error?

Comment: Is the file open in excel already? or are you trying to open it in the code?

Comment: Its not subscript out of range for filenum array it is subscript out of range for Workbooks.

Comment: So should I go back to the old question and reedit the post? I thought this would affect other viewers as then they will not be able to see my old mistakes

Comment: If anyone wants, they can always see the revision history. Until and unless it is a completely different question, you do not need to ask separate questions :)

Comment: Alright.. anyway i can take this question down? i can update the old one then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Subscript out of Range` would raise on that line if the required file is not already open.

Since it seems unlikely that you would already have 11 files open, you probably need to use the `Open` method to open the necessary workbook inside your loop.

`Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(filenum(lngposition) & ".csv")`.

**Updated your code**

```
Sub importData2()

  ChDir "C:\Users\Desktop\Java"
  Dim filenum(0 To 10) As String
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim wb2 As Workbook
  Dim sh2 As Worksheet
  Dim rng2 As Range 

  filenum(0) = "052"
  filenum(1) = "060"
  filenum(2) = "064"
  filenum(3) = "068"
  filenum(4) = "070"
  filenum(5) = "072"
  filenum(6) = "074"
  filenum(7) = "076"
  filenum(8) = "178"
  filenum(9) = "180"
  filenum(10) = "182"


  '## What workbook is this referring to?? This might cause problems later...
  Set rng = Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
  Set rng2 = Range("A69")
  Set wb = Application.Workbooks("30_graphs_w_Macro.xlsm")

  For lngposition = LBound(filenum) To UBound(filenum)

    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(filenum(lngposition) & ".csv")

    Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets(filenum(lngposition))

    Set sh2 = wb2.Worksheets(1)  'A CSV file only has 1 worksheet.

    sh2.rng.Copy Destination:=sh1.Range(rng2.Address)
  Next lngposition

my_handler:
  MsgBox "All done."
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817399/subscript-out-of-range-error-in-this-excel-vba-script

Comment: that's the 3rd time I've seen that bit of code... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799320/how-do-i-resolve-the-file-mismatch-in-this-vba-script

Comment: This opens up the file, and then it gives me the out of subscript error on the next line:
wb2.Worksheets(filenum(lngposition)).rng.Copy wb.Worksheets(filenum(lngposition)).rng2.Paste

Comment: Do **both** workbooks (`wb` and `wb2`) contain a worksheet which corresponds excactly to the name defined by `filenum(lngposition)`?

Comment: yes.. both workbooks have their sheets named 052 and so on

Comment: `052` is **NOT** in the `filenum` array.  What is the value of `filenum(lngposition)`? And please confirm that string matches a worksheet name in both files.

Comment: Oops.. yes I edited the post again.. and yes they do match.. wb1 and wb2 have a sheet with 052 as the name, also wb2 has the name 052.csv

Comment: Try: `wb.Worksheets(filenum(lngposition)).rng2.Value = wb2.Sheets(1).rng.Value`

Comment: I get the error object does not support this property or method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40655/discussion-between-user2883071-and-david-zemens)

Comment: I rewrote your code. Try the answer above and let me know if you still get any errors.

Comment: It gives a method or data member not found error at 
sh2.rng.Copy Destination:=sh.rng2
I changed sh to sh1 and then it gives a missing data member at .rng2

Comment: Try `sh1.Range(rng2.Address)` or simply `sh1.Range("A69")`.

Comment: So i did that.. then it gave me the message sh2.rng. is not a data member.. so i replaced that with sh2.Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).
now it gives me the subscript out of range error at Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets(filenum(lngposition))

Comment: Try `Dim filenum(0 to 10) As String` per my revision above.  A value like `052` when stored as `Long` data type will convert to `52`. If the worksheet name is `052` then this error is expected.  Although I would still expect an error in the `Set sh1 ...` statement.

Comment: Yes String works.. thanks!

Comment: Do consider "Accepting" this answer...

Comment: @SamWard This is the fourth time I've seen this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815472

Comment: @RichardMorgan yikes.  Well I think there was some confusion on OP's part. Several (many) issues/problems in the code, and s/he was under the impression that each discovered error requires a new question...

Comment: Yeah, I thought as I made changes I should open up a new post, so that other people could see my old mistakes

Comment: any chance i can take these questions down?

Comment: nah just leave them up at this point, especially if you have accepted answers on any of them. If some of them maybe do not have answers yet, then you might remove those.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely have `Set` on the line when you assign worksheets:

```
Set sh1 = Worksheets(filenum(lngPosition))
```

Comment: Thanks.. made the change